# Inserting a select statement into a table- ORA-06502

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I have 6 TEST environments and 1 production environment. I create quite a few different reports as Oracle views, and need a way to sync these between environments.

I am trying to make a script that I can run, which will basically output a list of commands that I can copy and paste into my different environment to create the necessary views/public synonyms and privileges.

I have to put the resultant text into a database table as `dbms_output.put_line` has a certain limitation on how many characters it can show.

I have the following, but if I try to insert the data, I get `ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error`. I am guessing this is probably got to do with character literals not being escaped and what not.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE EXPORT_REPORTS AS
  statements CLOB;
  tmp_statement CLOB;


  CURSOR all_views IS
     SELECT
      OWNER,
      VIEW_NAME,
      TEXT
    FROM
      ALL_VIEWS
    WHERE
      OWNER = 'PAS'
  ;
BEGIN
  FOR v IN all_views LOOP
    tmp_statement := 'CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "' || v.OWNER || '"."' || v.VIEW_NAME || '" AS ' || CHR(13) || CHR(10) || v.TEXT;
    statements := statements || tmp_statement;
  END LOOP;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO VIEW_EXPORTS VALUES ('''|| statements || ''')';
END EXPORT_REPORTS;
```

Any idea what I can do to try and fix this?
If it is because some of the text in the `statements` variable contains single quotes, how can I escape this before inserting the data into a table?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for Data Pump.

Oracle Data Pump technology enables very high-speed movement of data and metadata from one database to another.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/dp_overview.htm

For getting database object DDL I would recommend using the DBMS_METADATA package.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_metada.htm#BGBDJAHH

Answer (score -1):

you cannot use CLOB as a datatype for the local variables. Use VARCHAR instead

Comment: Not correct. I've got it working using CLOB. I simply changed the insert statement from an `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` to a `INSERT INTO...`